# Parallel calls response time in loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner, vugen

I have 3 get api calls. I have placed them in web_concurrent_start and end. How to check response time of each API in Loadrunner
My work: we can’t place lr_start_transaction and end inside web_concurrent_start and end. Can we use web_reg_async_attributes any example or suggestions is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

turn on time-taken in your HTTP logs